# I am struggling for when the user inputs aren't in range (works fine when IN range). I am aware of my mistakes, but I am having trouble fixing them

Tags: java, boolean

/* Teacher instructions:

- Boolean Conditions - Octets and IP Address
- 
- You are going to write a program that will accept 4 integer numbers from a user, check to see if they are valid
- IP address range numbers (1 - 255).(0 - 255).(0 - 255).(1 - 254)
- and then if they are valid you will put them in the correct dotted decimal notation for an IP address.
- If they are invalid, tell the user which one is invalid.
- 
- Sample Run:
  Please enter the first Octet:
  125
  Please enter the second Octet:
  10
  Please enter the third Octet:
  52
  Please enter the fourth Octet:
  10
  IP Address: 125.10.52.10
- 
- Sample Run:
  Please enter the first Octet:
  125
  Please enter the second Octet:
  10
  Please enter the third Octet:
  520
  Please enter the fourth Octet:
  10
  Octet three is incorrect.
- 

*/

My code (when user puts an octet that isn't within the range, it says its invalid, which I want it to do, but It also prints the given octets regardless of validity, when I don't want them being printed when one or more octet is invalid. In other words, I don't want them printed when invalid.):

```
enter code here


      //Ask for octets 1-4.
  System.out.println("Please enter the first octet:");
  int oct1 = scan.nextInt();
      
  System.out.println("Please enter the second octet:");
  int oct2 = scan.nextInt();

  System.out.println("Please enter the third octet:");
  int oct3 = scan.nextInt();

  System.out.println("Please enter the fourth octet:");
  int oct4 = scan.nextInt();


      //Add boolean to determine the octets' validity
      
  boolean invalid = false;

  if (oct1 < 1 || oct1 > 255){
     System.out.print("Octet 1 is invalid.");
     invalid = true;
  }
  if (invalid)
     System.out.print(""+oct1+"");
  
  if (oct2 < 0 || oct2 > 255){
     System.out.print("Octet 2 is invalid.");
     invalid = true;
  }
  if (invalid)
     System.out.print(""+oct2+"");    
  
  if (oct3 < 0 || oct3 > 255){
     System.out.print("Octet 3 is invalid.");
     invalid = true;
  }
  if (invalid)
     System.out.print(""+oct3+"");          
      
  if (oct4 < 1 || oct4 > 254){
     System.out.print("Octet 4 is invalid.");
     invalid = true;
  }
  if (invalid)
     System.out.print(""+oct4+"");
```

//If each octet is valid, determine invalid is false, and print IP address.

```
  if (invalid == false)
     System.out.print("IP address: "+oct1+"."+oct2+"."+oct3+"."+oct4+"");
```

}

}

Comment: As starting point, I suggest to not use the negative form of th verbs in booleans. In this case if you use `boolean valid` it will be more readable, and you will undersand which `if`s are wrong.
Then, if you don't want to print the octates, then change `if (invalid)` to `if (!invalid)`

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score -1):

Hope this satisy your requirements

```
import java.util.*;
public class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
       Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

       System.out.println("Please enter the first octet:");
       int oct1 = scan.nextInt();

       System.out.println("Please enter the second octet:");
       int oct2 = scan.nextInt();

       System.out.println("Please enter the third octet:");
       int oct3 = scan.nextInt();

       System.out.println("Please enter the fourth octet:");
       int oct4 = scan.nextInt();

       boolean invalid = false;

       if (oct1 < 1 || oct1 > 255){
       System.out.print("Octet 1 is invalid.");
        invalid = true;
       }

        //if (invalid)
        //System.out.print(""+oct1+"");

        if(oct2 < 0 || oct2 > 255){
        System.out.print("Octet 2 is invalid.");
        invalid = true;
        }
        //if(invalid)
        //System.out.print(""+oct2+"");    

        if (oct3 < 0 || oct3 > 255){
        System.out.print("Octet 3 is invalid.");
        invalid = true;
        }
        //if (invalid)
        //System.out.print(""+oct3+"");          
  
        if (oct4 < 1 || oct4 > 254){
        System.out.print("Octet 4 is invalid.");
        invalid = true;
        }

       //if (invalid)
       //System.out.print(""+oct4+"");
 
       if (invalid == false)
       System.out.print("IP address: "+oct1+"."+oct2+"."+oct3+"."+oct4+"");
       }
      }
```

Comment: Thank you so much.